# jQuery UI Dialog / Drag Question

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, draggable

Using jQuery UI Dialog.

Works great, but currently, when I drag a dialog, it will not move off screen (the entire dialog is always in the viewport).

Is there a way to set up the dialog so I can drag it partially off screen?

Comment: Why you want to move partially off screen ?

Comment: @ViswanathanIyer: Sometimes you need to move it out of the way a little to see something beneath it. I'm sure there are other reasons, but the question is **How?**, not why.

Comment: @ViswanathanIyer: they cover up the main area, but contain tools to make changes to that area, so user would bring up dialog, make a few tweaks, then drag it out of the way to see the changes. Right now, they would need to CLOSE it, then re-open it.

Comment: A "minimize" button would just be awesome... @OneNerd: I wonder if your users would actually think to drag offscreen? Sure, you and I know to do it - but depending on your audience it may not be very intuitive.

Comment: @Wesley Murch : Yeah, we have a double-click to minimize already, but just seems more natural that when you drag it, it wouldn't force-stop at the edge -- for me, I always want to drag it out of the way (as you say, maybe it's just me thought).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure you can if you extend the jQuery dialog code. Just include this code:

```
$.ui.dialog.prototype._makeDraggable = function() { 
    this.uiDialog.draggable({
        containment: false
    });
};
```

It will override the default containment value of 'document' with `false` which disables the containment.

Comment: Thanks - i'll tinker with this and see what I can come up with.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this fix, but no luck so far. I am loading it in my script.js file OUTSIDE of docready. (inside docready didn't work either).

This looks like a global change. Do I need to somehow relate it to each dialog?

Comment: +1 but this will replace some of the built in functionality, which you [can avoid if necessary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696461/jquery-ui-dialog-drag-question/7251026#7251026).

Answer (score 17):

Or you can do it in a simpler and more "jQuery way" ;)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dialog').
    dialog({
        //your dialog options go here
    }).
    dialog("widget").draggable("option","containment","none"); //this chained sequence kills containment  
});
```

Comment: you are the man!
I needed to constrain a dialog into a specific div (changed "none" to "#mydiv"). this is the solution.

Comment: totally champ. how do people figure out these gems? 

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue and was going to use [betamax's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696461/jquery-ui-dialog-drag-question/6696756#6696756), but noticed that it effectively replaces some of jQuery UI's built in functionality. So instead I adapted the approach to keep the built in functionality, but also turn containment off by overriding `_makeDraggable` rather than just outright replacing it:

```
if (!$.ui.dialog.prototype._makeDraggableBase) {
    $.ui.dialog.prototype._makeDraggableBase = $.ui.dialog.prototype._makeDraggable;
    $.ui.dialog.prototype._makeDraggable = function() {
        this._makeDraggableBase();
        this.uiDialog.draggable("option", "containment", false);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Play with the option, position. Write your own javascript calls to move the box.

```
   $('#dialog').dialog('option','position',[500, 100]);
```

but you cannot move the box out of the view-port, if you want to have such feature, write your own, extending the jquery ui dialog, (Update the code block where it checks for a valid position (valid if the position x,y are in the viewport)